# how to write package-info.java in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to write package level annotations. Can some tell how to write package-info.java in eclipse.

I want to add this info to it.

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema (
      elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED
      ...
    )
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You have to create the file in the package using `New -> File`.

`New -> Class` will not allow you to create the file because the file name is not accepted.

Answer (score 28):

When you do not have to generate the file after the package already exists, you can try to get into the habit of creating *packages* with right-click -> New -> Package: This offers you a checkbox `Create package-info.java`.

Comment: Following this answer, this is how eclipse(Neon.2) let me add package-info.java to an existing package: right click the package -> New -> Package; now leave the package name as is and click on the checkbox "Create package-info.java" and then create.

Comment: Well, that's something I would never have thought of! I can verify your observation with Mars.2.

Comment: The real LPT is always in the comments.

Comment: ...what is an LPT?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the class with any name. Remove the class definition code. Then rename the file in eclipse.